# One key on iPhone keyboard is not working

Tags: iphone, keyboard, screen

The letter "i" on my iPhone is not working anymore. I tried a factory reset, but it still isn't working. Other letters are working fine but there are other areas on the screen that seem to be less sensitive (e.g., the "6" on the enter password home screen). I know this manifested itself after I dropped the phone.

Can this be repaired (by whom?) or is my only option to get a new phone (or live without "i")?

Comment: I would simply recommend going to an [Apple Store](https://www.apple.com/retail/).

Answer (score 1):

> The letter "i" on my iPhone is not working anymore. ... Other letters are working fine but there are other areas on the screen that seem to be less sensitive (e.g., the "6" on the enter password home screen).

There are no "keys" on an iPhone screen.  The entire screen is a touch sensitive display that senses the coordinates of your finger press.  It just so happens to be where the letter "I" (or the number "8") is positioned.   Also, you have areas of less sensitivity; this will likely spread and become worse.

> I know this manifested itself after I dropped the phone.

You have the cause of this malfunction:  your screen is damaged.

> Can this be repaired (by whom?) or is my only option to get a new phone (or live without "i")?

Screen replacement is a very common repair.  You can take it to [Apple](https://support.apple.com/repair) themselves, an [authorized repair center](https://support.apple.com/repair/verify-repair-provider), or any reputable independent repair shop.

If you need to use your iPhone in the meantime (like to make a backup), you can use the USB to Lighting adapter and plug in a regular USB keyboard.  This will allow you to control your phone for the time being. Also, sometimes changing device orientation or [keyboard layout can help when only a portion of the touch is failing](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/add-or-change-keyboards-iph73b71eb/ios).